# Custom Route to About Razor Page in ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I would like to move the About page in the basic project that .Net Core 2.1 scaffolds to a location under a directory called Public (/Public/About.cshtml) but still have it called by the scaffolded menu item - i.e.

```xml
<a asp-page="/About">About</a>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If I understand. You moved the About page to some folder and need to generate URL for that razor page ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: What is the exact structure of pages? Does all the pages in Pages folders or Public is the root folder for all of them?

Comment: Pages has two directories - Shared and Public.  I want to move About as well as Contact from the Root directory of Pages to the Public Directory

Comment: So just change your `<a asp-page="/About">About</a>` to `<a asp-page="/Public/About">About</a>`

Comment: The whole point is that I want to keep the public route to the About page  /About.  I am creating the Public folder so that I can make it AllowAnonymous

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the documentation on how to configure a page rout? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-a-page-route

Comment: So in your About razor page view you can change the `@page` directive to `@page "/About"`

Comment: Changing to the page directive `@page "/About"` does not work

Comment: Thank you Nkosi - I have been at that page but am still confused about how to solve the seemingly simple challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving your **About** page to a new sub-folder **Pages/Public** and still want to keep "/About" as the URL of that page you can modify your route for that page this is what to do:

Change `<a asp-page="/About">About</a>` to `<a asp-page="/Public/About">About</a>`

`asp-page` tag helper expects a path to your razor page file not the URL. It will generate the final URL based on conventions or custom routes you add.

In your `ConfigureServices` method you need to configure that **/Public/About** razor page should use `/About` as a route and not `/Public/About` which will be the default if you don't configure it. So you must have this in your method:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(
        options => options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Public/About", "/About")
    );
```

The first parameter of `AddPageRoute` method is the path to the razor page and the second parameter is the new route. So if you execute your application and click on `About` link you'll se that `/About` will point exactly to `/Public/About`. The browser also doesn't contain `/Public/`.

Check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-a-page-route) if you want to learn more about custom routing for Razor Pages.